# Push Notification to multiple users

Tags: javascript, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am developing an app that allows all the Flat Owners in a Society to add their Cook through the app itself. I am storing all data in Firebase. The Flat owner adds his Cook's details in the app and when the Cook enters the society for his service, the Guard authenticates the Cook and the Flat owner through a push notification.

Now the problem is, when there is a Cook who works only for one Flat, then the Push Notification goes through perfectly. But when a Cook works for multiple Flats, then only one Flat Owner gets notified. The one who is at top in the Firebase structure, under 'Cook' branch.

I want all Flat Owners to get the notified through push notification.

I am mentioning my JavaScript code here which acts as a mediator to perform device to device notification process. I think I need to make changes here itself.

```
exports.dailyServiceNotification = functions.database.ref('/dailyServices/all/public/{dailyServiceType}/{dailyServiceUID}/status')
  .onWrite((change, context) => {

    const dailyServiceType = context.params.dailyServiceType;
    const dailyServiceUID = context.params.dailyServiceUID;

    return admin.database().ref("/dailyServices").child("all").child("public").child(dailyServiceType).child(dailyServiceUID).once('value').then(queryResult => {
      const status = queryResult.val().status;
      if(status.localeCompare("Not Entered") === 0)
        return null;

      return queryResult.forEach((userSnap) => {
        var userUID = userSnap.key;
        console.log("User UID : " + userUID);

        return admin.database().ref("/users").child("private").child(userUID).once('value').then(queryResult => {
        const tokenId = queryResult.val().tokenId;
        const payload = {
          data: {
            message: "Your " + dailyServiceLookup[dailyServiceType] + " has " + status + " your society.",
            type: "Daily_Service_Notification"
          }
        };

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokenId, payload).then(result => {
          return console.log("Notification sent");
        });             

      });

    });

  });

});
```

Comment: I have exaplained in one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)** step by step, how you can send **[notifications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RzB4HXzQyA&t=3s&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=17)** but using Cloud Firestore, not Firebase Real-time database and Node.js. If you are interested, you can take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
exports.dailyServiceNotification = functions.database.ref('/dailyServices/all/public/{dailyServiceType}/{dailyServiceUID}/status').onWrite((change, context) => {
  const dailyServiceType = context.params.dailyServiceType;
  const dailyServiceUID = context.params.dailyServiceUID;
  const promises = [];
  return admin.database().ref("/dailyServices").child("all").child("public").child(dailyServiceType).child(dailyServiceUID).once('value').then(queryResult => {
    const status = queryResult.val().status;
    if (status.localeCompare("Not Entered") === 0) return null;
    queryResult.forEach((userSnap) => {
      var userUID = userSnap.key;
      const uP = admin.database().ref("/users").child("private").child(userUID).once('value').then(queryResult => {
        const tokenId = queryResult.val().tokenId;
        const payload = {
          data: {
            message: "Your " + dailyServiceLookup[dailyServiceType] + " has " + status + " your society.",
            type: "Daily_Service_Notification"
          }
        };
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokenId, payload);
      });
      promises.push(uP);
    });
  }).then(() => {
    return Promise.all(promises);
  });
});
```